How to suppress stdout within a specific python thread?
I want to be able to suppress any print to stdout within a specific thread. Here is what I have tried:
import sys, io, time
from threading import Thread

def do_thread_action():

    # Disable stdout
    sys.stdout = io.StringIO()

    print("don't print this 1")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("don't print this 2")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("don't print this 3")

    # Re-enable stdout
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

thread = Thread(target=do_thread_action)


thread.start()

time.sleep(1.5)

# Print this to stdout
print('Print this')

thread.join()

However this does not work because sys.stdout is global for both thread and the main thread.
How do I suppress the prints inside do_thread_action within the thread, but not suppress the prints outside of it?

I am not sure if that is possible, but if it is, the way to do it is monkey-patch sys.stdout with a thread-local object. I will try that and come back with a full answer if I perceive it can work.

Do you have control over the print statements in the thread? If so, you can change the file parameter to print to a different stream. For example, writing to /null, you could add nullstream = open(os.devnull,"w") and then add file=nullstream.

@ipodtouch0218 no, in my real code the threads run functions from a library that I I cannot edit. I want to suppress within the thread anything that is sent to stdout

@Wilson what about this solution then? They make a proxy object to intercept the result of sys.stdout in only a single thread. Seems like it's what @jsbueno was trying to do.

So, here it is - just replace the sys.stdout object by an object with a write (and to encompass all cases, a flush) methods which can select where the output should go for the currently running thread.
And they can check the currently running thread using the thread name.
Here is an almost "production ready" class which can take care of things, including even the decorators for patching the codepaths which should be guarded for printing:
import time
import threading
import io
from unittest import mock
import sys

delayed_outputs = None

class SelectOutput():
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.text_io = io.StringIO()
        self.ns = threading.local()
        self.config = config


    def filter(self, func):
        def wrapper( *args, **kwargs):
            # in this example, thread_id is passed as
            # a parameter, but one could also use
            thread_id = threading.current_thread().name
            if thread_id in self.config and self.config[thread_id] == "capture":
                self.ns.stdout = self.text_io
            else:
                self.ns.stdout = sys.__stdout__

            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    def instrument(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            #global all_outputs
            with mock.patch("sys.stdout", self):
                # all_outputs = tmp
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    def write(self, text):
        self.ns.stdout.write(text)

    def flush(self):
        self.ns.stdout.flush()

select_output = SelectOutput(config={"2": "capture"})

@select_output.filter
def target(thread_id):
    time.sleep(0.1 * thread_id)
    print(f"At thread ID: {thread_id}")
    time.sleep(0.2 * thread_id)
    print(f"closing thread ID: {thread_id}")

@select_output.instrument
def instrumented():
    threads = []
    for thread_id in (1, 2, 3):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=target, args=(thread_id,))
        # name the threads so that each is identified when they are running:
        thread.name = str(thread_id)
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()


    [t.join() for t in threads]

def main():
    global delayed_outputs
    delayed_outputs = io.StringIO()
    instrumented()
    print("Delayed outputs:", select_output.text_io.getvalue())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()



Brilliant solution! In my own implementation, I removed config from the class and instead split filter into two wrappers, filter and dont_filter which could each be applied to corresponding target functions.
